# Dividing a list into diagonals?

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix, diagonal

If I have this list of lists:

```
l = [
['a','r','v','s','s','t','n','g'],
['e','x','a','m','p','l','e','t'],
['g','z','n','p','u','t','x','m'],
['v','a','h','g','i','k','t','f']
]
```

How can I easily divide it into a list of list according to diagonals?

The result I'm going for is pretty much:

```
[
['a'],
['r','e'],
['v','x','g',],
['s','a','z','v'],
['s','m','n','a'],
```

and so on...

I also should mention, I have numpy installed it that helps in any way.

Answer (score 3):

```
[ [ v[d-i] for i,v in enumerate(l) if d-i>=0 ] for d in xrange(len(l[0])) ]
```

Developing this is stages:

```
[ <one-diagonal-row> for <index d of each element of first row of input> ]

[ [<element-of-diagonal d> for <each v, which is row i of l>] for d in xrange(len(l[0])) ]

[ [ v[d-i] for i,v in enumerate(l) <only if element exists>] for d in xrange(len(l[0])) ]
```

which gets you to the expession at the top.

Comment: You should strive to provide explanations rather than just dump code to the OP.

Comment: @Rapptz: The level of explanation was commensurate with the level of effort demonstrated by the OP, but I take your point.

Comment: Your answer was posted on the low quality queue (which made it a candidate for deletion) due to it being a code dump. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: @Rapptz: And yet it has the highest rating; interesting.

Comment: Also, the other diagonal is obtained with `[ [ v[d-len(l[0])+i+1] for i,v in enumerate(l) if d-len(l[0])+i+1>=0 ] for d in xrange(len(l[0])) ]`

Answer (score 2):

This is the most explicit way for you to understand:

```
lists = [
['a','r','v','s','s','t','n','g'],
['e','x','a','m','p','l','e','t'],
['g','z','n','p','u','t','x','m'],
['v','a','h','g','i','k','t','f']
]

diagonals = []
for i in range( len(lists[0])+len(lists) - 1):
    diagonal = []

    for lst in lists:
        if len(lst)>i and i>=0:                 
            diagonal.append(lst[i])     
        i-=1

    diagonals.append(diagonal)

for lst in diagonals:
    print(lst)

diagonals = [
['a'],
['r', 'e'],
['v', 'x', 'g'],
['s', 'a', 'z', 'v'],
['s', 'm', 'n', 'a'],
['t', 'p', 'p', 'h'],
['n', 'l', 'u', 'g'],
['g', 'e', 't', 'i'],
['t', 'x', 'k'],
['m', 't'],
['f']
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by taking advantage of the fact that the indices of each diagonal will sum to a given integer.

Given a list `lst`, we have:

```
diagonals = [[''.join(c for j,c in enumerate(s) if i+j == n)
              for i,s in enumerate(lst)]
             for n in range(len(lst[0]))]
```

Or in this particular example:

```
In [15]: lst = ['arvsstng', 'examplet', 'gznputxm', 'vahgiktf']
In [16]: [[''.join(c for j,c in enumerate(s) if i+j == n) for i,s in enumerate(lst)] for n in range(len(lst[0]))]
Out[16]: 
[['a', '', '', ''],
 ['r', 'e', '', ''],
 ['v', 'x', 'g', ''],
 ['s', 'a', 'z', 'v'],
 ['s', 'm', 'n', 'a'],
 ['t', 'p', 'p', 'h'],
 ['n', 'l', 'u', 'g'],
 ['g', 'e', 't', 'i']]
```

If you would like to have different length lists in the output, you can just run a filter over it:

```
In [18]: diagonals = [filter(None, sublst) for sublst in diagonals]

In [19]: diagonals
Out[19]: 
[['a'],
 ['r', 'e'],
 ['v', 'x', 'g'],
 ['s', 'a', 'z', 'v'],
 ['s', 'm', 'n', 'a'],
 ['t', 'p', 'p', 'h'],
 ['n', 'l', 'u', 'g'],
 ['g', 'e', 't', 'i']]
```